# Android apk above 100mb cant be installed into the device

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I had developed an android that the apk is 100mb+. I realise that if my apk is less than 100mb, it will be able to be installed with the apk but if the apk is more than 100MB it says "application not installed" and gives me an error when I tried installing into my device using the apk file. Could someone please tell me why? and how do I fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: please tell me the reason why or how should i fix this instead of downvoting this, because i am just a beginner and i am searching for a reason and method to fix this. Thx

Comment: And as beginner, how come, you start with such large applications? It doesn't happy often if you're going by the guidelines...

Comment: it is because i am developing and app that have videos and stuff and the videos are the one that make it huge T.T

Comment: Agreed, instead of tackling the installation barrier, you should tackle your apps size. You probably included loads of resources/raw data. Host your data somewhere (for free or paid is your choice). If you use Google Play as a distribution platform, they offer to host 4GB of data for you.

Answer (score 2):

See documentation: https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html

> **Google Play currently requires that your APK file be no more than 50MB**. For most applications, this is plenty of space for all the application's code and assets. However, some apps need more space for high-fidelity graphics, media files, or other large assets. Previously, if your app exceeded 50MB, you had to host and download the additional resources yourself when the user opens the app. Hosting and serving the extra files can be costly, and the user experience is often less than ideal. To make this process easier for you and more pleasant for users, Google Play allows you to attach two large expansion files that supplement your APK.

So you should be using expansion files to install such large application, but I wonder, **are you completely sure the application has to be this large?**

Comment: i see the reason now . Thank you very much for the reply. I really appreciate it.